# Add an oval shape into a PDF surrounding the highlighted text

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

```py
import fitz
def highlight_text(pdf_file, room_id):
        for page in pdf_file:
            ### SEARCH
            text = str(room_id)
            print(text)
            text_instances = page.search_for(text)

            ### HIGHLIGHT
            for inst in text_instances:
                highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
                highlight.set_colors({"stroke":(0, 1, 0), "thickness": 2})  # <-- change thickness here
                highlight.update()
                print(highlight)

                # create a shape object
                shape = page.new_shape()
                # draw a circle with width=5 (change it to whatever you want)
                shape.draw_circle(((inst.x0+inst.x1)/2, (inst.y0+inst.y1)/2), 70)
                shape.finish(color=(0,1,0), fill=None, width=5)
                # update the page with the drawing
                shape.commit()

            ### OUTPUT
            pdf_file.save("highlighted.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)


pdf = fitz.open("OK31017-ML0100-DWG-ZA-B1.pdf")
highlight_text(pdf, "MECH PUMP ROOM (WATER FEATURE 12)")
```

I have tried a rectangle to surround the highlighted text. Now, I would like to change it to a circle, and increase the stroke thickness, so that it will be more visible.

I'm using Python `3`.

Comment: Post a [mre]. What library are you using? What is the type of ```pdf_file```?

Comment: I am using tkinter, PyPDF2 and fitz. I am using this code to find words from a Pdf drawing. Also, honestly, I don't know how to reproduce a minimal one from the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer,

```
                circle_center = fitz.Point((inst.tl.x + inst.br.x)/2, (inst.tl.y + inst.br.y)/2)
                circle_width = 300
                circle_height = 150
                circle_bbox = fitz.Rect(circle_center.x - circle_width/2, circle_center.y - circle_height/2,circle_center.x + circle_width/2, circle_center.y + circle_height/2)
                circle_annot = page.add_circle_annot(circle_bbox)
                circle_annot.set_colors(stroke=(1,0,0), fill=(1, 1, 0))
                circle_annot.set_border(width=10)
                circle_annot.set_opacity(0.7)
                circle_annot.border_width = 10
                circle_annot.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Shape` object to draw circle:

```py
    def highlight_text(self, pdf_file, room_id):
        for page in pdf_file:
            ### SEARCH
            text = str(room_id)
            print(text)
            text_instances = page.search_for(text)

            ### HIGHLIGHT
            for inst in text_instances:
                highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
                highlight.set_colors({"stroke":(0, 1, 0), "thickness": 2})  # <-- change thickness here
                highlight.update()
                print(highlight)

                # create a shape object
                shape = page.new_shape()
                # draw a circle with width=5 (change it to whatever you want)
                shape.draw_circle(((inst.x0+inst.x1)/2, (inst.y0+inst.y1)/2), 70)
                shape.finish(color=(0,1,0), fill=None, width=5)
                # update the page with the drawing
                shape.commit()

            ### OUTPUT
            pdf_file.save("highlighted.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
```

[image]

Above is the result of below code:

```py
import fitz
...
        pdf = fitz.open("table.pdf")
        self.highlight_text(pdf, "12345678")
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no circle seems to appear.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I am getting the circle, but, how can I make appear as bounding over the selected word?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but more precisely, the circle is appearing on a random location, and not bounding the word? Any idea why?

Comment: As it works for me, so there should be something else in your code causing your issue.  It is better to post a [mre].

Comment: Sure! I have edited the code to include a reproducible example. Please try out with a pdf drawing.

Comment: It also works for me using your updated code with my sample PDF. Basically your updated code is the same as mine.

Comment: Is the circle appearing over you text? Mine is not, the highlighted text is on one side, and the circle is in another point.

Comment: what did you use as your sample PDF?

Comment: I have already posted the screenshot of my sample PDF with the circle over the highlighted text.

Comment: What do you think is the problem in my code?

Comment: I have already said your code works for me, so how can I know why it does not work for you?